# Polynomials having all zeros in the closed left half plane

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Let $$P(z) =\sum_{k=0}^n(\alpha_k+e^{i\gamma}\beta_k)z^k=P_1(z)+e^{i\gamma}P_2(z)$$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with $\alpha_k, \beta_k\geq 0$ for $0\leq k\leq n, $  where   $$P_1(z) =\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_kz^k \quad\text{ and} \quad P_2(z) =\sum_{k=0}^n\beta_kz^k. $$  The polynomial $P(z)$ makes  $P_1(z), P_2(z)$ behave alike in some aspects in some specific domain of $\gamma,$ for example if $P(z)$ is self reciprocal, then $P_1(z), P_2(z)$ are also self reciprocal in the sector  $0\leq \gamma<\pi.$  I have been thinking about if $P(z)$ has all its zeros in the closed left half plane (say) then is there any sector opening by $\gamma$ where $P_1(z), P_2(z)$ also have all zeros in the same half plane?

I would be grateful, if   you suggest any reference material.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by self reciprocal?

Comment: A polynomial $P(z)$ is self reciprocal if  $P(z)\equiv z^nP(1/z).$

Comment: This is reminiscent of gamma-positivity of polynomials, and how this relates to real-rootedness, see the survey by Athanasiadis.

Comment: @ Per Alexandersson, I would greatly appreciate if you share the   title of the survey.

Comment: @user159888 https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05983  Also, Thm. 2.6 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.04141.pdf is similar, it related real-rootedness of a 'big' polynomial with its two 'parts' in a symmetric decomposition. This feels conceptually close to what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Per Alexandersson.